# Upgrading but get unmet dependencies grub-common:i386

Tags: apt, grub2, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

Try to upgrade and get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub2-common:i386 : Depends: grub-common:i386 (= 2.02-2ubuntu8.23)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

However if I do that I get:

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/grub2-common_2.04-1ubuntu45_i386.deb: trying to overwrite '/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub', which is also in package grub-efi-amd64 2.04-1ubuntu44.1.2
```

I have no clue how to solve this. Please help.

ls -d /sys/firmware/efi gives:
**config_table efivars esrt fw_platform_size fw_vendor runtime runtime_map systab vars**

echo UEFI gives **UEFI**

echo BIOS gives **BIOS**

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS`

Comment: Please use cp and paste for my command.